# can I execute and intent(to open a layout) and play a sound in the same button onclick event?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using something like this (but its not working):

```
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

public void presentacion_Onclick(View v){

          Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityPresentacion.class);
          Log.v(TAG, "Initializing sounds...");


         final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.presentacion_personal);

            Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Presentacion_main_btn);
            play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Playing sound...");
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
            Log.v(TAG, "Sounds initialized.");   

            startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: Move `mp.start()` out to `presentacion_Onclick()`. There's no need to create another `OnClickListener`.

Comment: How is `presentacion_Onclick(...)` called?

Comment: BTW: you do not `execute` any Intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you go over the docs of `MediaPlayer.create()`, it says:

> Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id. On
>   success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be
>   called again.

Now, if you call `start()` while the `MediaPlayer` has not been prepared, it makes no difference - it will not play. Rather, make your class implement `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener` and set `this` for your `MediaPlayer`'s on prepared listener.

In the `onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)` method, call `mp.start()`.

If you are playing the same sound over and over, just create one `MediaPlayer` instance that you use to play the sound.

Comment: The static `create(...)` method of `MediaPlayer` is synchronous so basically calling it means it won't return until the `MediaPlayer` instance is prepared or, if there is an error, it returns with a `null` `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: @Squonk Ah yes, you are right. I confused it with `prepareAsync()`. The OP must now, more than ever, use a 'global' `MediaPlayer` instance to avoid any lags caused by preparing the `MediaPlayer` again and again! :)